# Is there any python library to plot a static map with a specific country in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have previously used some python libraries like `folium`, `matplotlib` etc. These libraries render nice, dynamic maps in Django template, but take a lot of time to load. Also, I want the static map for a specific country where places can be marked with their respective `latitudes` and `longitudes`.

The map should be something like this:
[image]

So, is there any python library that renders static maps in Django template with relatively less loading time than those by `folium`, `matplotlib`?

Comment: If rendering a map takes a long time, only render it once and cache it somewhere?

Comment: Please review what is on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. Questions asking us to find or recommend an off-site resource, like a library, are explicitly _off-topic_ as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: @Chris Although in the question it seems like I am asking for a tool, I also meant to ask that are there any better practices with `folium`. `matplotlib` etc. to reduce loading time of map.

Comment: @onapte, you are literally asking for a library recommendation: "Is there any python library to plot a static map with a specific country in Django?" If that isn't what you mean I suggest you [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

For me the best option would be to use leaflet, for example choropleth, it's free and have tons of options:
[Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/)

It's a js library but fully compatible with django template, i use it several times.

[Django integration](https://django-leaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: This does not answer OP's request for rendering static maps.

Comment: It can be used to plot static maps, it have a lot of options... To use something else would be to create a canvas with a static image.

Comment: Library recommendations are off-topic as defined in the [help/on-topic]. [Please don't answer off-topic questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/354577).

Comment: @Chris He is asking exactly for a library that he can use, I think that in this case it is not applicable...

Comment: @Pablo, no the help center is pretty clear: "Questions asking us to _recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource_ are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: @Chris a new thing I learn, I was just trying to help.

Comment: @Pablo, I really appreciate the effort. Answering questions here takes time and most users don't contribute back. Your attitude and contributions make this place better. It's just that some questions aren't a good fit here. Thanks for being receptive.